# How to implement voice over ip in iOS?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, voip

I want to make voice/video calls between iPhones App using WiFi/Internet. How should I do that? I don't want to make calls on service provider number. It will make calls between apps on different iPhones like skype.

I didn't fount any way to search. I am getting confuse how to start working on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

U need to use VOIP service, there are lots of VOIP API but maximum are paid.
check apple doc:
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/AdvancedAppTricks/AdvancedAppTricks.html

Check This also
[Twillo](http://www.twilio.com/)

Comment: Hi Sachin
Thanks for your reply
But link you shared me is not sufficient.
I have found one Library http://www.pjsip.org/
This is free but unable to integrate in project.
Also I googled search not found proper solution. Max are not working or not explain properly how to integrate
Can you please help me.

Comment: Twillio is for paid. I don't want to use it. If possible i need to have some solution on pjsip library or any other free working library.

Comment: Ok, There is open source c library pjsip http://trac.pjsip.org/repos/wiki/Getting-Started/iPhone Check out this. If you want to do server side then go for opensips http://www.opensips.org/

Comment: Hi, i know pjsip is hard to integrate, there is one more lib is there. they have sample project also and rich documentation. in my project i used this only. http://www.linphone.org/eng/documentation/dev/liblinphone-free-sip-voip-sdk.html

Comment: Link is dead, did you mean this page: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH7-SW24 or did you have a better one?