# Is it possible to transfer Linphone SIP call to an iOS native call?

Tags: ios, call, sip, linphone

I am wondering if it is possible to send an SIP call using Linphone to the device? I have looked around and I do not see it mentioned anywhere.

Comment: Apple provides VOIP service to run in the background.   Add VOIP in your plist to enable. For more info http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17040307/how-to-implement-voice-over-ip-in-ios

Comment: I can already run it in the background. I want to transfer a SIP call using Linphone to a iOS call. A call that would be controlled by the native dialer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use CallKit, it uses the native interface for incoming calls. Take a look at apples docs.